# Duplicate in module import suggestion typescript, nodejs on visual studio code

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

As suggestions from some articles I read, I should `npm install` type declarations in dev dependencies. But, I get annoyed as everytime I import module, vscode shows something like this. Is there any way I can prevent it happens?
[image: Duplicate modules]

This is my dependencies list:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "ajv": "^5.5.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "helmet": "^3.9.0",
    "java": "^0.9.0",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.11.0",
    "@types/helmet": "0.0.37",
    "@types/java": "^0.7.32",
    "@types/morgan": "^1.7.35",
    "tslint": "^5.8.0",
    "typedoc": "^0.9.0",
    "typescript": "^2.6.2"
  },
```

Update: tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": false,
    "inlineSources": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: what's your tsconfig.json?

Comment: @unional I strictly defined typeRoots

Comment: Try remove it. You typically don't need to define `typeRoots`